# Errors in -a MIRA training using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing my project on hand gesture recognition using OpenCV, C++ code. After feature extraction, there is a need of training, and testing. for that I have downloaded the format from CRF++ yet another toolkit. I  am using now crf++-0.54 version. I have used " crf_learn -a MIRA Templatefile Trainfile Model_crf" format.

I have prepared both template and train file in '.CSV' format.

But it showing the following error:
MIRA doesn't support multi-thrading. use thread_num=1.

waiting for solution.................

Answer (score 0):

You could try crf++ in a newer version since version 0.55 includes a fix about multithreading support. Latest available version on the website is 0.58 by the way.